# How do I save .py files in IPython notebook with the .ipynb files

Tags: ipython, jupyter-notebook

How do I set my IPython Notebook so that whenever I save the `.ipynb` file it will also automatically save the file as a `.py` file (in the same directory)?

In particular every time I make a change to a notebook I don't want to have to download the file as a `.py` file and then move the downloaded file into the directory.

I recently moved to a Mac and was able to do this on my previous (PC) setup, but haven't been able to find how to explicitly set IPython to do this.

Comment: how did you do it on your PC setup?

Comment: I don't remember as it was several years ago.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can start the notebook server with a `--script` flag, or set this variable to True in the file `ipython_notebook_config.py`:

```
c.FileNotebookManager.save_script = True
```

Comment: I might need to add `c = get_config()` beforehand in the config file

Comment: I think the config files are created with that line at the top, but if they're not, yes, you'll need to add it.